# Закрытие 80 порта

Tags: nginx

Подскажите, пожалуйста, а можно ли каким-то образом сделать так, чтобы 80 порт при проверках казался закрытым, но http-запросы мог принимать?

Comment: Он кажется закрытым, если при соединении с ним происходит отказ в соединении или хост просто не находится. Чтобы обслуживать HTTP-запросы, соединения нужно принимать. У меня впечатление, что вы решаете какую-то связанную проблему очень странными средствами.

Comment: @D-side да я не решаю ничего. Товарищ создал сайт на VPS в reg.ru, и попросил меня поискать в нём возможные дыры. Я просканировал порты и заметил, что 80 порт закрыт. Но это если получать к порту доступ по IP. Если по домену, то там всё нормально.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, а как вы сканировали 80-й порт?

Comment: @D-side при помощи nmap.

Comment: @D-side детальный отчёт nmap показал, что у 80 порта статус filtered.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin,почитайте краткое описание для выдаваемых nmap-ом резюме: https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать на уровне IPtables (linux firewall) пропуск пакетов через 80 порт только с определенным User-Agent. Далее меняете User-Agent у вашего браузера на заданный.

Comment: Но тогда это будет работать только для меня. А как же остальные юзеры? У них ведь будет другой UserAgent.

Comment: Вопрос был не корректно поставлен. Ограничение должно быть задано к определенному сайту, который находится на сервере ?